# DOMXPath - How can we search a js object using php

Tags: php, web-scraping, domxpath

I want to get a specific js object from a different url using php.

Or

I want to get js script text from a different url using php.

I am using this approach.

```
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$ddoc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
if(!empty($html)){ //if any html is actually returned
$ddoc->loadHTML($html);
libxml_clear_errors(); //remove errors for yucky html
$xxpath = new DOMXPath($ddoc);
$rrrow = $xxpath->query("//script[contains(@src, 'pcode')]");

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You neglect to state what, if anything, is happening with your code. I tried vitrually an identical approach and it worked perfectly ( see below ) so without knowing the url which you are trying to target I would suggest that you try adding a context to the `file_get_contents` as, in many cases, a server can be configured to reject requests where there is no `User-Agent` string present.

```
$url='http://beautifulbathrooms.tumblr.com/';
$query='//script[contains(@src,"jquery")]';



$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->validateOnParse=false;
$dom->standalone=true;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace=true;
$dom->strictErrorChecking=false;
$dom->substituteEntities=false;
$dom->recover=true;
$dom->formatOutput=false;
$dom->loadHTML( file_get_contents( $url ) );
libxml_clear_errors();


$xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );
$col=$xp->query( $query );
if( !empty( $col ) ){
    foreach( $col as $script ) echo $script->getAttribute('src').BR;
}
```

With a context argument to `file_get_contents`

```
$url='http://beautifulbathrooms.tumblr.com/';
$query='//script[contains(@src,"jquery")]';

$args=array(
    'http'=>array(
        'method' => 'GET',
        'header' => implode( "\n", array(
                    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0',
                    'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
                    'Host: beautifulbathrooms.tumblr.com'
                )
            )
        )
    );
/* create the context */
$context=stream_context_create( $args );


$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->validateOnParse=false;
$dom->standalone=true;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace=true;
$dom->strictErrorChecking=false;
$dom->substituteEntities=false;
$dom->recover=true;
$dom->formatOutput=false;
$dom->loadHTML( file_get_contents( $url, FILE_TEXT, $context ) );
libxml_clear_errors();


$xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );
$col=$xp->query( $query );
if( !empty( $col ) ){
    foreach( $col as $script ) echo $script->getAttribute('src').BR;
}
```